# Fast way to find bracket in php

Tags: php, regex, parsing

I have a string like this:
(...1 (...2 DS(...3 ( ...4 ) ) ) )

Which the best idea to find data in DS brackets if I don't know how much brackets after DS before it end? (3, 4)
Its like math: multiply ds on the 3 and 4 brackets.

Comment: You'll probably have to implement an small parser, using a Stack to manage which set of parentheses you're currently looking at.

Comment: See the answer of @shiplu.mokadd.im for a reasonable example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can not be done by regular expression. Its not a [regular language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language). Its general parsing.

```
$data  = '(...1 (...2 DS(...3 ( ...4 ) 5) )6 )';
$num   = array();
$start = strpos($data, 'DS') + strlen('DS');
$end   = strlen($data) - 1;
$paren = 0;
for ($i = $start;$i <= $end;$i++) {
    $n = $data[$i];
    if ($n == '(') $paren++;
    if ($n == ')') $paren--;
    if ($paren >= 0 && is_numeric($n)) {
        $num[] = $n;
    }
}
print_r($num);
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible using regex.
Regex is unable to save how many open parentheses are there...

You should code it by php.

Answer (score 0):

does this work with it?

```
preg_match_all('/DS\(...(\d)+ \)?\(?[DS]?/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Take the substring from the place where DS occurs using the function substr, and get the data out of it.
To get the data, just parse the substring keeping a count of opening brackets. When the closing brackets start, keep a count of them. When this count and previous count become equal, you have got your data.

Comment: He doesn't "know how much brackets after DS before it end?", which implies that he needs the contents of DS to be balanced with respect to parentheses. So a simple substring won't do it.